# GEE: edit location of "Layers" + "Map/Satellite" selection widgets

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a GEE app with a left/right split map.
Per default the "Layers" + "Map/Satellite" selection widgets are located on the top-right.
For the panel on the right that's alright, but becomes a bit annoying for the left side, in case I want to select different layers.

Is there any way to move them to a different location? In my case, top-left.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own layer selectors using ui.Select widgets and placing them anywhere you want.  The "User Interface -> Split Panel" example in the code editor demonstrates this and how to change out the layer when one is selected.

```
// Adds a layer selection widget to the given map, to allow users to change
// which image is displayed in the associated map.
function addLayerSelector(mapToChange, defaultValue, position) {
  var label = ui.Label('Choose an image to visualize');

  // This function changes the given map to show the selected image.
  function updateMap(selection) {
    mapToChange.layers().set(0, ui.Map.Layer(images[selection]));
  }

  // Configure a selection dropdown to allow the user to choose between images,
  // and set the map to update when a user makes a selection.
  var select = ui.Select({items: Object.keys(images), onChange: updateMap});
  select.setValue(Object.keys(images)[defaultValue], true);

  var controlPanel =
      ui.Panel({widgets: [label, select], style: {position: position}});

  mapToChange.add(controlPanel);
}
```